# wait() and exit() with parent-child processes

Tags: c, fork, wait, exit

A fork has already occurred in code:

```
if (pid == 0) {
    printf("I am child PID %d\n", getpid());
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
} else {
    pid_t child;
    int status;
    //need wait() function that gets child pid and exit status
    printf("Child PID %d terminated with return status %d\n", child, status);
}
```

As commented in the code, I need an appropriate wait function that will wait for child to end and get the PID and resulting exit status code of the child. Thanks!

Comment: -1 Are you serious? Just how far have you searched? How about `wait()`?

Comment: I guess maybe I am moderately confused on the implementation. wait() returns a pid value so if I do: child = wait(&status); it should return the pid of the child, right? I get -1 for the value of child.

Comment: Read the manual, it explains everything. `If wait() or waitpid() returns due to the delivery of a signal to the calling process, -1 shall be returned and errno set to [EINTR].`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html), or [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) (same page, really).

Or, if you're on BSD, `wait3()`, or `wait4()` (but not, AFAIK, `wait2()`).